# Animate words from left to right

Tags: jquery, animation

I want to use animation to move words from left to right every time, How can I do that? The current code is not working for me.

```js
$("#networkHeading").css('color','#03709b').animate({'left':0}, "slow");
```

Comment: We need to see all the related HTML, CSS and JS to solve this issue, as there could be any number of issues preventing this from working.

Answer (score 0):

Just moving text from left to right? Just use simple html `marquee` tag.

```
<marquee attribute_name = "attribute_value"....more attributes>
In uncommon move, Apple hikes iPhone, iPad prices in Japan after yen tanks
</marquee>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/pu6e5zo4/2/